# Chrome (v86) adds head body tags to empty.html page, where's the documentation?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-devtools

I've spent quite some time using dev tools, but just noticed that when I open an empty .html file chrome renders:

`<html><head></head><body></body></html>`

It's a bit unnerving to see 'auto' added elements, but can see the special case.  Where is behaviour like this documented?  I'd like to know if there are other scenarios when the browser takes such actions.

Comment: Devtools shows a serialized version of the actual live DOM in the element inspector. An html document object always has head and body when it's fully parsed. This is per specification.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks, is this where I should look [html standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html)?

Comment: See [tag omission](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/sections.html#the-body-element) and [this note](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#syntax-tag-omission).

Comment: @wOxxOm yep, perfect thanks.  The fine print of webdev!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As wOxxOm states, the Web Hypertext Application Technology Working Group standard specifies that, if omitted, certain tags are implied.  The `<body>`  [tag spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/sections.html#the-body-element) states the effect of omission.

Some examples are given of expected browser behaviour in case of tag omission in the [13.1.2.4 Optional](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#syntax-tag-omission) tags section.

What I thought was a lack of rigour by chrome was actually spec driven behaviour ensuring that poorly formed/ non- HTML is parsed.

Thank you for the links wOxxOm .